# How can I give a "hint" on what time unit to use?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, executorservice, scheduledexecutorservice

I have a class that schedules tasks via a scheduled executor.
I want the class to be parameterized on the `TimeUnit`. I mean I want to be able to construct the class with the delays etc for the thread pool and a way to specify the `TimeUnit` e.g. if it is seconds/milliseconds/minutes etc.
Is using a `String` parameter and then doing:

```
if(param.equals("seconds")){  
  timeUnit = TimeUnits.SECONDS;  
}
```

etc
the only way here or is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use TimeUnit directly as the type of your parameter. Spring can bind enums without problem.

Comment: I am not using spring yet.I want a solution that if I use spring in the future,it will work as well

Comment: @Jim: Have you checked that you can't specify a TimeUnit in Spring? I'd expect it to work...

Comment: @JonSkeet:I am **not** using spring yet.I am looking for a solution that will work *if* I make the class a spring bean.I will spring from OP as it confused

Comment: @Jim: You seem to have missed my point. This answer is the most appropriate one, and I believe it will *still* work when you use spring. You want to know a `TimeUnit` - so make the parameter a `TimeUnit`. Why would you *want* to introduce a string here?

Comment: @JonSkeet:Ah!I understand what you mean!Thanks for pointing out my confusion.